# Redirect to different URL when current URL contains some string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement wherein I need to redirect my page to a different URL when my current URL contains some string.

For instance,

If my current URL contains [www.testdomain.com](http://www.testdomain.com) or [www.testdomain.com/web/region](http://www.testdomain.com/web/region) then it should redirect to [www.testdomain.com/group/region](http://www.testdomain.com/group/region). I tried the below code but it returns "The requested resource could not be found -- [https://www.testdomain.com/web/region/testdomain.com/group/region"](https://www.testdomain.com/web/region/testdomain.com/group/region%22).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf("web/region") > -1) {
window.location.href=window.location.hostname+'/group/region';
}
})
```

It is adding the URL twice here. But when I pass the direct URL **window. location.href="www.testdomain.com/group/region"** it is working.

Can someone guide me on how do I force redirect my page if the URL contains [www.testdomain.com](http://www.testdomain.com) or [www.testdomain.com/web/region](http://www.testdomain.com/web/region)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with `//` so that the browser knows it's not a relative URI:

```
window.location.href = '//' + window.location.hostname+'/group/region';
```

You can also prepend the protocol:

```
window.location.href = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname+'/group/region';
```

Comment: couldn't you just set `window.location.pathname = '/group/region'` ? or use `window.location.assign()` or `window.location.replace()` as appropriate?

Comment: Tried with assign and replace and it returns the same result. Adding '//' fixed the issue. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's adding the URL twice because browsers interpret `/group/region` as a relative path, automatically prepending the current domain UNLESS otherwise specified. *(Maybe others can explain why `window.location.hostname` doesn't immediately return, thus preventing the browser from assuming a relative path?)*

Example: If you explicitly set a domain, the browser will redirect to it as expected.
`window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'`

Otherwise, if you take away "www."
`window.location.href='google.com/'`
Your browser will redirect to "www.testdomain.com/google.com", appending the string.

### The fix is simple.

Just delete `window.location.hostname+` and it will only return the URL once.

**Or...** for a better user experience, I would suggest using `window.location.replace()` which [DOES NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) save the current page in session history.(You don't want to go back, just to be redirected again!)

### SOLUTION:

Replace your return block with this.
`window.location.replace('/group/region')`